send request to WOPI via HttpClient c#
I have web app and WOPI app. I have .docx document, I need to do some changes with content of that document and I need to save the resulting .docx document as PDF in my storage.
I've investigated here that we can use /wv/WordViewer/request.pdf?WOPISrc={WopiUrl}&type=downloadpdf for downloading documents as PDF.
So, I want to execute that request via HttpClient and get in result pdf file.
Here is my code:
WopiSecurity wopiSecurity = new WopiSecurity();
var token = wopiSecurity.GenerateToken(command.CurrentUser.Id, userName, tempDocxFileId, false, true, 1, this._wopiOptions.Value);
var accessToken = wopiSecurity.WriteToken(token);
var accessTokenTtl = (long)token.ValidTo.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;

var wopiSrc = this._wopiOptions.Value.WopiUrl
           .Replace(":tenantguid", tenant.LongGuid.ToString())
           .Replace(":guid", _fileGUID);

var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new("access_token", accessToken),
    new("access_token_ttl", accessTokenTtl.ToString()),
    new("user_id", command.CurrentUser.Id.ToString()),
    new("owner_id", command.CurrentUser.Id.ToString()),
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var url = $"https://ffc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com/wv/WordViewer/request.pdf" +
    $"?wopisrc={wopiSrc}" +
    $"&type=downloadpdf";
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  throw new ContainerValidationException(new List<string> { "error in request to download pdf" });
}
else
{
  var resultStr = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var pdfFileStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}

But in the result I have:
404 - File or directory not found.
Can I execute queries in such way? Or it's impossible? Or something wrong in my code?

Are you a member of the "Office 365 Cloud Storage Partner" program?

Have you tried to use the method GET instead of POST?

This is a browser request, should be GET i.e. httpClient.GetAsync

@Nikolay @Fernando Del Cantão if I use .GetAsync I have the same result - 404 error

@Dai how does it help me?

@A.Gladkiy The docs imply that if you aren't in the program then you won't have permission/rights to use WOPI - which would explain the issue you're facing.

@Dai the error should have been not 404 if this was the case. Also the WOPI works according to the topistarter. Does it?

@Nikolay yes, WOPI works for standard behaviour (I mean WOPI host page iframe and submit form with the access_token etc...)

What I meant was, you can view/edit word documents with your WOPI setup, right? I mean, you (your organization) is a member of the Cloud Storage Program? Only members of that program are allowed to access that URL (ffc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com), i.e. there is whiltelisting.

@Nikolay yes, I just can't execute request to WOPI via HttpClient. When I go to WOPI host page and there is automatically submit form - works fine.

I may be missing the point. What do you mean by "wopi page", i.e. what do you "submit"? It should be a normal word document that you should be able to view with WOPI. Does this work for you?

@Nikolay Yes, I see normal Word document. I meant how normally WOPI works. 2 apps. The first - WOPI host page where <form> with link to the document and access_token etc and we submit form to <iframe> and in this iframe I see the document. And the second app - WOPI handler, where I implemented CheckFileInfo, GetFile, PutFile etc methods
